# Cart array data not being processed with form data

Tags: php, forms

Overview: I have a shopping cart (cart.html.php) to collect user selections to be emailed. If the  cart count > 0, I include a form (quote.html.php) to collect prospect info. On submission, the form posts the prospect's data and sends an email of that data. I want to also include the cart content.

Problem: when I set the action of the form to action="", or action="." in order to process in on the index.php, so I can loop through the cart content (foreach($cart as $item) the form will not submit.

If I set the action to action="process-rfq.php", the form processes the form data correctly but not the cart. The cart array remains behind, throwing a foreach error.

Thus, both options fail and I do not know what to do to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: The code will definitely help here. If you use `action=""` the form will `GET` or `POST` on the same url. In that file, if you decide to include or not another file, it's not something influenced by the url used to get there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This box is too small for the three files. Is there another way to show the code?

Comment: Perhaps if I keep action="process-rfq.php" and assign the cart array content to $_SESSION['cart'], then I can loop through it and display the content in the email. If this works, it still doesn't answer why the form will not process @index.php, which is my preference. I want index.php to control everything.